# It is possible to create OIDC app in google workspace dashboard?

Tags: single-sign-on, openid-connect, saml, google-sso, custom-application

using "custom SAML app" option in Google admin console. in our company we are able to create SAML app in Google, is there any option we can use OIDC SSO protocol instead of SAML protocol to create "custom OIDC app"